# Where is my Google map marker?

Tags: google-maps-markers

I'm trying to get my single marker to show on the Google map, my coordinates are right, and the map shows, just I dont know the code for the marker. Can anyone help? Here is a link to the live page here - [Live google map page](http://www.seosocial.com.au/google-map.html)

Answer (score 0):

You never call the function `pan()` that contains the marker creation in your code. That's why you don't see it.